# Gerar uma tabela utilizando template String e innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

Em um exercício,estava tentando criar uma tabela através da DOM utilizando template string e o comando innerHTML

**Local aonde quero inserir os td**

```
<tr id="boletinAluno">

</tr>
```

**Criando o aluno**

```
function cadastrarAluno(e){

    let nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value
    let nota1 = document.querySelector('#nota1').value
    let nota2 = document.querySelector('#nota2').value
    let nota3 = document.querySelector('#nota3').value

    let aluno = new Aluno(nome,nota1,nota2,nota3)

    montarLinha(aluno);



}
```

**MontarLinha**

```
function montarLinha(aluno){
        let content = `
        <td>${aluno.nome}</td>
        <td>${aluno.nota1}</td>
        <td>${aluno.nota2}</td>
        <td>${aluno.nota3}</td>
        <td>${aluno.getMedia}</td>

        `
       boletin = document.querySelector('#boletinAluno').innerHTML+=content;


    }
```

**ERRO**

```
index.html:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at montarLinha (index.html:89)
    at cadastrarAluno (index.html:75)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:39)
montarLinha @ index.html:89
cadastrarAluno @ index.html:75
onclick @ index.html:39
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#boletinAluno')` está retornando `null`, verifica se tua função não está antes do HTML que criar esse elemento.

Comment: O script é criado após a criação da TR,ou seja não é o problema.